# how to show shipping method selection for each item in cart

Tags: magento2, module, cart, shipping-methods, magento-community

Can anyone give the solution for the below.
I am using magento 2 CE. I want to show all shipping methods for each item in the cart on the shopping cart page and the customer can select the shipping method seperately.
How can i achieve this? please give the solution 
[image]

Comment: This question Does not showing any Research Efforts. Stack overflow is not a Code generator. you have to research and work yourself first. If not works and then only you need to ask here with your researched / tried codes.

Comment: I'm also facing this challenge and on the path of making shipping/delivery item manageable on line item level.
Did you have any success achieving it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 //$objectManager is an instance of \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface

 $session = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');

 $shipping = $session->_getCheckoutSession()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

 $methods  = $shipping->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to show all the shipping methods for each item. The user can select one shipping method for first item[free shipping] and select another one [truck delivery] for another item. how to i make that selection process ?

Comment: So in your template, use $method in each product ?
And ofcourse you have to custom some tables (sales_order,..) to save shipping method for each item in an order.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will try and get back to you.